# Word for collective followers of Sisyphus

Tags: single-word-requests, modifiers

I am looking for a single word to describe the group of followers of Sisyphus (or generally any Greek name ending in '-phus'). I am unsure of how to modify the word to achieve this.

**Possible guesses**: Sisypheans, Sisyphees, Sisyphians.

**Example sentence**: "Despite their differences, the men were all ____"

**Related**: The word 'sisyphean' is used to describe an endless or immensley repetitive task, so 'Sisypheans' might be ambiguous as used to describe the followers of Sisyphus.

**Relevant research:** The OED lists both 'sisyphean' and 'sisyphian' but none of the examples use the word to mean 'people/followers of Sisyphus'. Further, search results for 'sisypheans' yields only references to an album with that name.

The word 'Sisyphians' is used in the Marie Belloc Lowndes 1904 novel "The Heart of Penelope", Chapter II:

"Mr. Gumberg hesitated; words
sometimes failed him, but never for long-'all I can say is he was
the first of those I was the first to dub the Sisyphians ... // ... Those for whom I invented the name of Sisyphians-there are
plenty of 'em about now—well, i divide 'em into two sets, both, I
need hardly say, equally distasteful to me. The one kind cultivates
platonic friendships with the women'-Mr. Gumberg made a slight
grimace."

In this example, 'Sisyphians' is a fictional name given to these people due to their actions relating to or resembling those of Sisyphus, but not as followers of Sisyphus. I am unsure of whether there is any way English meaningfully distinguishes between the two via suffixes.

Comment: The Wikipedia article for Pythagorus contains << School: Pythagoreanism >>. But have you checked for 'Sisypheans'? Ambiguities occur frequently in English, and are dealt with by using forcing context. 'The Sisyphean school held the belief that ...'.  //Any followers of Sisyphus would probably be short-lived.

Comment: Actually, when you suggest Sisypheans might be ambiguous to describe the *followers of Sisyphus*, are they following Sisyphus or his famous actions? So is there a difference?

Comment: I am afraid you are in for a bit of an uphill struggle with this one.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The OED lists both 'sisyphean' and 'sisyphian' but none of the examples use the word to mean 'people/followers of Sisyphus'. Further, search results for 'sisypheans' yields only references to an album with that name.

Comment: Then that should be in the question as relevant research. I take it you _do_ mean the paywalled OED and not the other fine Oxford dictionary of English, Lexico? // [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sisyphean) actually includes << **Sisyphean**:  1. relating to Sisyphus >>. I don't see _how_ it can possibly  count this as the default sense. The 'primary' sense, yes.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes referring to the paywalled OED. I have added my research in as well as an example in literature. As Yosef says the difference between following Sisyphus vs following their actions is difficult to differentiate.

Comment: There is a well established term for the followers of Pythagoras, because he, in fact, had followers. There is no well established term for the followers of Sisyphus, because it is rather unclear what would it be for someone to be a follower of Sisyphus.

Comment: As King of Corinth, any loyal subjects he amassed could be called Sisypheans, according to Collins. But there's not a lot of background to this, and it's myth in any case. The question's example sentence certainly allows Sisypheans, but doesn't clarify what that really is supposed to mean. They recognised him as their king? They were prepared to lay down their lives in battle for him? They believed that he'd actually chained Thanatos, ensuring humans would henceforth never die? They liked his maths classes?(?!)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's a totally satisfactory answer for me. I see that my example sentence is ambiguous in what it means to be a follower (idealogical or otherwise) but the example as King of Corinth is perfect, a better example is how the 'Aeneads' refer to the followers of 'Aeneas'. Presumably similar Greek '-phus' names would behave similarly with the '-eans' suffix replacing the '-us'

Comment: You could probably get away with assuming the 'rule' (_Pythagorus's Last Theorem_?) is as productive as you wish; people will assume the adjectives exist but are esoteric. I can't see much loss of clarity resulting if more precision than 'somehow associated with ...' is forced by suitable choice of context.